# 4043 error from SELECTION-LIST

Tags: progress-4gl

I have a SELECTION-LIST defined as:

```
 DEFINE VARIABLE sel_TPlate AS CHARACTER 
     VIEW-AS SELECTION-LIST MULTIPLE 
     SCROLLBAR-HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL 
     SIZE 36 BY 17.86
     FONT 60 NO-UNDO.
```

The list contains hundreds of items with each item ranging from 10 - 40 characters. When a user selects multiple items, they are stored in a character variable.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE listItems        AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
listItems =  sel_TPlate:SCREEN-VALUE.
```

I understand that this error is caused by exceeding the 32k limit, but I am unsure of the best way to solve this problem. I have attempted to change the variable and list to a LONGCHAR, but this does not solve the issue. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Progress?

Comment: We are currently using Progress 11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection lists are appropriate for relatively small collections of data.  Not for picking hundreds of items.

Instead of using a SELECTION-LIST you should be using a BROWSE associated with a temp-table where each selection is a row in the TT.

A temp-table & browse combination is only limited by available memory and will overflow to disk if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Tom, this is the answer we went with.